# How to use and condition in logstash if statement

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok, logstash-configuration

I need to use `and` in logstash filter I'm doing something like this

```
if "domain" in [message] and "[100]" in [message] { drop { } } but its not working getting configuration error
```

I also tried doing `if "domain" and "[100]" in [message] { drop { } }` but its not dropping any logs

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Share your full logstash pipeline, your first option is the correct way, if it is not working than the problem could be in other parts of your pipeline.

Comment: Try perhaps with `if [message] =~ "domain" and [message] =~ "\[100\]"`

Answer (score 2):

Try the below,

```
if [message] == "domain" and [message] == "100" {
   drop { }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How to use and condition in logstash if statement.

---

```
filter{  mutate {      remove_field => ["@timestamp","@version","tags"]   
} if ![customerId]{         drop{ }   }
```